# PostgreSQL - get matched value of array field in the result

Tags: sql, postgresql

If I have a query that looks for a list of values in an Array column, is there a way to get the `matched` value as a computed column in result table?

Imagine the following query:

```
SELECT name, tags
FROM Books
WHERE Books.tags && ARRAY['APLLE', 'ORANGE']::varchar[]
```

This is what I intend to have as result:

```
| name    | tags              | query    | <- I WANT query COLUMN
|---------|-------------------|----------|
| Cooking | {APPLE, EGGPLANT} | "APPLE"  |
| Frying  | {TOMATO, ORANGE}  | "ORANGE" |
| Boiling | {APPLE}           | "APPLE"  |
```

Comment: Can you use plsql or just standard SQL?

Comment: @VladCălinBuzea, yep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select name, b.tags, (
    select string_agg(t,',')
    from
        unnest(b.tags) t(t)
        inner join
        unnest(v.tags) s(t) using (t)
    ) as query
from
    books b
    inner join
    (values (array['APPLE', 'ORANGE']::varchar[])) v(tags) on b.tags && v.tags
;
  name   |       tags       | query  
---------+------------------+--------
 Cooking | {APPLE,EGGPLANT} | APPLE
 Frying  | {TOMATO,ORANGE}  | ORANGE
 Boiling | {APPLE}          | APPLE
```

The data:

```
create table books (name text, tags varchar[]);
insert into books (name, tags) values
('Cooking','{APPLE, EGGPLANT}'),
('Frying','{TOMATO, ORANGE}'),
('Boiling','{APPLE}');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION array_intersect (array1 varchar[], array2 varchar[]) RETURNS varchar[] 
  AS $$ 
     DECLARE 
       out VARCHAR[];
       i varchar;
     BEGIN 
        IF array1 IS NULL OR array2 IS NULL THEN 
           RETURN NULL; 
        END IF; 
        FOR i IN array1 LOOP 
           IF (i = ANY (array2)) THEN 
              out := array_append(out,i); 
           END IF; 
        END LOOP; 
        RETURN out; 
     END; 
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

And then

```
SELECT name, tags,  array_intersect(tags, ARRAY['APLLE', 'ORANGE']::varchar[])
FROM Books
```

Comment: Can you point to the docs? I don't seem to find `array_intersect`.

Comment: I updated my answer. It seems that array_intersect is not a standard function

Comment: `create or replace function array_intersect(anyarray, anyarray) returns anyarray immutable language sql as $$
  select array_agg(t1.v) from unnest($1) as t1(v) join unnest($2) as t2(v) on (t1.v=t2.v)
$$;`

Comment: You should declare the function `STRICT` so that you do not have to test for `NULL` parameter values. Otherwise, this will also produce a row where a book does not have any of the tags in the array (`query` column will be `NULL`) which is different from what the OP posted and it is _very_ inefficient.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT name, tags, fruit AS query
FROM Books
JOIN (VALUES ('APPLE', 'ORANGE')) f(fruit) ON true
-- or JOIN unnest(ARRAY['APPLE', 'ORANGE']::varchar[]) f(fruit) ON true if so desired
JOIN unnest(Books.tags) b(tags) ON b.tags = f.fruit;
```

This will give you multiple rows for a single book if more than one of the book's tags matches the array values. If you want to avoid that use:

```
SELECT name, tags, string_agg(fruit, ', ') AS query
...
GROUP BY name, tags;
```